# (unity) My canvas's position and size is insane when the render mode is set to screenspace overlay (the width is tiny and height is massive)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

[image: Here is a pic]

As you can see everything is bizarre. The height is a number with 26 zeros next to it and the width is basically zero. the position is also just as bizarre and I have no idea why

All I did was try to create a simple canvas I have no idea how this happened or what is going on and I feel like I messed something up

[image: (rest of the settings)]

Comment: Doesn't happen for me ^^ => probably need a bit more context. Maybe some weird settings in the CanvasScaler ?

Comment: tbh its position is irrelevant..  It is normal for the canvas to be a huge bunch bigger than your scene

Comment: @BugFinder but not with the values OP has (see picture) ^^

Comment: I editted it to add the rest of the settings @derHugo

Comment: try setting it to scale - then you will be prompted for the default size from which it will shrink or grow to match

Comment: I tried but didn't really do much good. Putting it to grow didn't change any of the values no matter what I did and putting it to shrink made the width zero no matter what I did